# Team Foundation Server Build Tasks - Escape Characters?

Tags: macos, tfs, tfsbuild

I am using TFS 2017.  I have some Build definitions for iOS applications that run on a Mac OSX Agent.  Those Build defs contain one or more Shell (Bash) Script  and Command Line tasks.  In these tasks I am trying to use environment variables that are on the physical Mac computer.  The problem is, to use the Mac's environment variables I need to send a "$" via the TFS Build Task.  It seems to get lost in translation when TFS sends it to the Mac Agent  (I'm assuming because the Build def uses "$" for its own variables).  Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

COMMAND LINE TASK:

Tool

```
/TEE/tf
```

Arguments

```
checkin -comment:"Advance Version Number - $(SolutionName) to $(< newversion.txt) (TFS BuildNumber:  $(Build.BuildNumber))" "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/$(Info.plist.Path)" -login:$(TfsLogin),$(TfsPassword)
```

And the resulting changeset in TFS:

```
Advance Version Number - MyiOSSolution to $(< newversion.txt) (TFS BuildNumber:  20180124.53)
```

The previous Build task is a Bash script that updates the Version Number of an iOS project (in the info.plist file) and also creates the file "newversion.txt".  "newversion.txt" contains a single line with the new version number.  It proved very difficult to persist an environment variable once the previous Bash Script terminates.  So I am instead trying to write the new version number to a file that can be picked up in the succeeding Build Task(s).

The goal in this Command Line Task is to use TEE (Team Explorer Everywhere) to checkin the changed info.plist file.  And also use the new version number in the checkin comment.

Using "$(< newversion.txt)" in a terminal works fine.  But when executed as part of a TFS Command Line Build Task, "$(< newversion.txt)" is interpreted as literal text.  I assume TFS is not sending/executing the arguments properly since it knows "$(< newversion.txt)" is not a valid TFS variable - so it sends that piece as a literal.

Comment: What's the variable name? "< newversion.txt"? Is there a blank space in the variable name? And did you restart your build agent after add the variable on your machine?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the [VSTS Variable Tasks extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jessehouwing.jessehouwing-vsts-variable-tasks) from the Visual Studio Marketplace.

> When you define a variable in the Variables screen and use other variables as value, they won't be expanded (as you may have expected). Instead, the literal text is passed to the tasks in the workflow. Without this little task the following configuration won't work:
>
> ```
> Variable              Value
> Build.DropLocation    \\share\drops\$(Build.DefinitionName)\$(Build.BuildNumber)
> ```
>
> By adding the Expand variable(s) task to the top of your workflow, it will take care of the expansion, so any task below it will receive the value you're after.

<sup>https://github.com/jessehouwing/vsts-variable-tasks/wiki/Expand-Variable</sup>